# MySQL syntax error caused by weird array value which shouldn't be there?

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-error-1064

This is really, really weird.

Basically, I have a MySQL syntax error occurring because of quotes in this string:

```
('Justin Bieber', '12312688'
 , 'http://a2.twimg.com/profile_images/1468693614/Inkwell_normal.jpeg', '0'),
('Nicki Minaj', '5422852'
 , 'http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/1520039676/325789956_normal.jpg', '1'),
('Drizzy Drake', '2989144'
 ,'http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/1483569177/drake-toronto_normal.jpg', '7'),
('Lil Wayne WEEZY F', '3058376'
 ,'http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/712863751/lil-wayne-gq-2_normal.jpg', '6'),
('Kanye West', '4176631'
 ,'http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/1132696610/securedownload_normal.jpeg', '4'),
('Wiz Khalifa', '2846894'
 ,'http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/1400724773/5fa42d61-2b5e-4b12-ac9f-4e673c97ef16_8_normal.jpg', '8'),
('Beyonce Knowles', '1607181'
 ,'http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/140949372/Beyonce_64_normal.jpg', '9'),
('KELENDRIA ROWLAND', '1214446'
 ,'http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/1418081050/KELLY_ROWLAND_cover_8181v2_normal.jpg', '10'),
('Lupe Fiasco', '819343'
 ,'http://a2.twimg.com/profile_images/1450626759/209893_10150145920132282_8128837281_6973183_7422817_o_normal.jpg', '11'),
('Tinie Tempah', '761045'
 ,'http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/1315150186/Tinie_Black_Jacket_Pic_normal.jpg', '13'),
('50cent', '4918067'
 ,'http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/1508833809/street-king-energy_normal.png', '2'),
('TRINA ', '796672'
 ,'http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/1441338027/Trina4372_normal.jpg', '12'),
('iamdiddy', '4012130'
 ,'http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/1299211308/OG_FADER_FORT_DAY_4_19_normal.jpg', '5'),
('mediatemple', 
 '('Justin Bieber', '12312688'
   ,'http://a2.twimg.com/profile_images/1468693614/Inkwell_normal.jpeg', '0')'
   ,'http://a2.twimg.com/profile_images/421686554/mt-125x125-dk__d5d6295_normal.jpg', '14'),
  ('Chris Brown ', '4284795'
   ,'http://a2.twimg.com/profile_images/1515163027/image_normal.jpg', '3')
```

More specifically this portion, of which the Justin Bieber related part shouldn't be there:

```
('mediatemple', 
 '('Justin Bieber', '12312688'
   ,'http://a2.twimg.com/profile_images/1468693614/Inkwell_normal.jpeg', '0')'
   ,'http://a2.twimg.com/profile_images/421686554/mt-125x125-dk__d5d6295_normal.jpg', '14')
```

Here's my actual code:

```
$screennames = array(
                 0 => "JustinBieber",
                 1 => "NickiMinaj",
                 2 => "drakkardnoir",
                 3 => "LilTunechi",
                 4 => "kanyewest",
                 5 => "RealWizKhalifa",
                 6 => "beyonce",
                 7 => "KELLYROWLAND",
                 8 => "LupeFiasco",
                 9 => "TinieTempah",
                 10 => "50cent",
                 11 => "TRINArockstarr",
                 12 => "iamdiddy",
                 13 => "mediatemple",
                 14 => "chrisbrown"
                     );

for($i = 0; $i < 15; $i++) {
$xml[$i] = @simplexml_load_file('http://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.xml?screen_name=' . $screennames[$i]);
$name[$i] = $xml[$i]->name;
$followers[$i] = $xml[$i]->followers_count;
$imageurl[$i] = $xml[$i]->profile_image_url;
}

$rank=-1;

arsort($followers, SORT_NUMERIC); 
foreach ($followers as $key=>$value) {
    $rank++;
  $ranks[$key]=$rank;
}

for($i = 0; $i < 15; $i++) {
    $value[$i] = "('".$name[$i]."', '".$followers[$i]."', '".$imageurl[$i]."', '".$ranks[$i]."')";
}
for($i = 0; $i < 14; $i++) {
    $value_string .= $value[$i].",";
}

$value_string .=$value[14];
```

For reference, it queries the Twitter API, retrieves specific data about each `$screenname` value, then concatenates it into one big string for `(...) VALUES $value_string`, however on `$value[13]` it seems to just place `$value[1]` right in the middle of it.

**So far I've tried;**

Using implode (which always returns a function error).

Just using `$value_string .=$value[$i].","` in the first for loop which leaves a trailing `,`.

Changing `$screennames` values around.

I just don't understand what could be causing this issue.

Any help/answers/comments would be very, very, very much appreciated :)!!

**UPDATE 1**

Here's the final portion of my code, for good measure:

```
include("db_conn.php");
$conn = mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass) or die(mysql_error()); mysql_select_db($db_name) or die(mysql_error());

$query = "INSERT INTO twitter (name, followers, imageurl, rank) VALUES $value_string";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_close($conn);
```

Comment: works as expected for me sure you not adding the extra ( in when you run the query?

Comment: Nope, but even if, it wouldn't explain why `$value[1]` is also inside of `$value[13]` when `$value_string` is echoed.

Comment: is the problem visible if you do a die($value_string); after your last statement?

Comment: @Ben, Yeah it's still visible :(.

Comment: We need to see where value_string is being set and we need to know what the error is on implode.

Comment: @cwallenpoole - I'll edit my OP in a minute to show the error. Need to re-run the script, and can't properly because of Twitter API rate limiting which is due to reset in a minute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fixed:

replace from first for loop down

```
for($i = 0; $i < 15; $i++) {
   $value_string .="('".$name[$i]."', '".$followers[$i]."', '".$imageurl[$i]."', '".$ranks[$i]."'),";
}

$value_string=rtrim($value_string,",");
echo $value_string;
```

also removes the 2nd for loop which is rather pointless.

Answer (score 1):

The problem disappear for me if I declare $value as an array before using it:

```
$value = array();   // <-- here
for($i = 0; $i < 15; $i++) {

    $value[$i] = "('".$name[$i]."', '".$followers[$i]."', '".$imageurl[$i]."', '".$ranks[$i]."')";

}
```

Explanation: *I think the problem is that $value is used before as a scalar variable first in the foreach ($followers segment, then as an array afterward. weird combination*

@Pixelatron. If you want to bypass the rate limit, just cache the results in a temp file for testing..

```
$xml[$i] = @simplexml_load_file('http://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.xml?screen_name=' . $screennames[$i]);
file_put_contents("temp/".$screennames[$i],$xml[$i]->asXML());
```

and then comment that off, and load the cache instead of the loading the remote xml

```
$xml[$i] = file_get_contents("temp/".$screennames[$i]);
$xml[$i] = simplexml_load_string($xml[$i]);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! And thanks for the caching, although this is now finished and I can deliver it to my client, I'll definitely bear it in mind next time I go about using the Twitter API (their rate limit really does suck, especially if you're using shared hosting, Facebook allows something like 600 requests per 10 minutes).

Answer (score 1):

It is not immediately a solution, but I cannot see any call to `mysql_real_escape()` in your code. This would make your code safer, for the case that somehow a `'` gets in one of your strings.

For tracing down your bug, you should try to put some `var_dump()` or `print_r()` calls in order to know the values of the various arrays.

And, try to replace the constant values spread throughout your code by appropriate `count()` results.

Comment: Data isn't posted, so `mysql_real_escape()` doesn't really fulfill a purpose in this code. I've already accepted Dagon's answer, but thanks for your help!

Comment: Posted data is not the only source of, ermm, data with unusual content. As I pointed out, a `'` can even stem from a maybe corrupted xml file. It is better to `mysql_real_escape()` all strings being put in a database. That lets you the freedom not to have to worry what gets put in, you can put in everything without danger.